# Automatic Bluetooth Connection between Android and iOS phones

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, mobile-application

What i mean to do is an application which automatically sends messages to nearby smartphones in public, for example when the user is going shopping or walking around town and he only has to have the phone in his pocket. Of course both phones would have the app downloaded and enabled.

I only find Unity Plugins that can do a manual communication between phones (e.g. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/bluetooth-le-for-ios-tvos-and-android-26661 ), which means that you have to manually start a connection from your phone to the nearby one. I'd really like to have this an automatic process!

**Looking for either a Unity Plugin or solution in C# or some other way of handling this in C++ or Java.**

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Swift library that allows you to do what you wanted:

https://github.com/insidegui/MultipeerKit

Test if it works the way you wanted and try to integrate it with unity :)

Comment: This looks actually great, thank you very much for answering! I'm gonna come back after testing it out.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this approach is for iOS devices only

Comment: Can't you combine it with android?